# When we use a scroll view and Recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

In a app we have a activity which displays a list of textview let us take a list of numbers 1-9 or more than that.Which  view is useful to display textviews either scroll view or Recycler view?

Comment: `list of textview` itself says Use `RecyclerView`.

Comment: If your dealing with the list of items / group of items / dynamically changed item count then go for Recycler View... If you have some content which is more than your screen size then go with Scroll view.  ( Let say simple large Image view and some two buttons )

Answer (score 0):

**Recyclerview** itself has scrollbar implemented in it. It is used when you have a large dataset.
**ScrollView** is used when you have a limited set of children on your UI and they are fitted out of your screen, so ScrollView is implemented here to scroll your layout to see all the children.